# How do I print lines in between two searches

Tags: python, regex

My text as follows:

```
FEATURE AAA cdslmd 22.02 28-jul-2023 1 \
3F76BA3DA7102935AD12 VENDOR_STRING=J:PERM DUP_GROUP=NONE \
vendor_info=13-jun-2023 \
ISSUER=CDNS2161b9360e2037d6f7bd35a11244661a ISSUED=13-jun-2023 \
EC0C" V7.1_LK=3F06FAFDD30D943EC2DD

FEATURE BBB cdslmd 22.02 28-jul-2023 2 7F061A2D977BFEF08F2F \
VENDOR_STRING=J:PERM DUP_GROUP=NONE vendor_info=13-jun-2023 \
ISSUER=CDNS2161b9360e2037d6f7bd35a11244661a ISSUED=13-jun-2023 \
A843" V7.1_LK=BFC68A9D5606A8296604
```

Expected result:

```
FEATURE AAA cdslmd 22.02 28-jul-2023 1 \
3F76BA3DA7102935AD12 VENDOR_STRING=J:PERM DUP_GROUP=NONE \
vendor_info=13-jun-2023 \
ISSUER=CDNS2161b9360e2037d6f7bd35a11244661a ISSUED=13-jun-2023 \
EC0C" V7.1_LK=3F06FAFDD30D943EC2DD
```

My script:

```
import os
import re

pat1 = r"[A-Z]+.AAA"
pat2 = r"[^\\]$"

with open('all.txt') as f:
    match = False

    for l in f:
        if re.match(pat1, l): 
            match = True
            print (l) 
            continue
        if re.search(pat2, l): 
            match = False
            continue
        if match:
            print (l) 
f.close()
```

Outcome of above script:

```
FEATURE AAA cdslmd 22.02 28-jul-2023 1 1F469A0DE7A48BDAE16B \
```

It is printing only one line that starts with `pat1`. I wanted to print lines between `pat1` and `pat2` (where the end of line does not end with "" after `pat1`).

Comment: This can be done with a single regexp, and no for-loop. For example, something like this should work: `txt = f.read(); print(re.search(r'^[A-Z]+\s+AAA.+?\s+(?:^.+?\\\s+)+^.+$', txt, re.M).group())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r"[^\\]$"` will match the newline character (`\n`) at the end of every line. You don't need a regex for that check though, you can simply do

```
if not l.strip().endswith('\\'): 
    match = False
    continue
```

Additionally, to get your desired output, i.e. also print the line that does not end with `\`, you will need to switch the order of your if statements:

```
        if re.match(pat1, l):
            match = True
            print (l)
            continue
        if match:
            print (l)
        if not l.strip().endswith('\\'):
            match = False
            continue
```

Alternatively, pattern2 could also be `r"[^\\]\n$"`, but I feel like the first approach is easier to read